# How to make a stopwatch that takes a widget off the air?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to know how to make this stopwatch, which after 48 hours disables a widget, which in my case is a button. Can someone explain to me how to do it? What classes to use?

I tried to use this, but don't works:

```
var timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () => print('done'));
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that you want this button to be disabled after 2 days of the app that was installed, you need persist the date on the device so that after app-restarts the date will be itself, you need to use a package the persists the data on the device. i recommend shared_preference which is easy to use.

for your case, in the screen where you use the button you need to do this

```dart
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class MyFirstStatefullScreen extends StatefullWidget {
  MyFirstStatefullScreenState createState() => MyFirstStatefullScreenState();
}

class MyFirstStatefullScreenState extends State<MyFirstStatefullScreen>{
// some other code that u wrote 
  bool shouldButtonBeActive = true;

 @override
 void initState() {
    Future.delayed(Duration(0))
          .then((_) {
         SharedPreferences sharedPrefs= await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

         final deadLine = sharedPrefs.getString('deadLine');

         if(deadLine == null) {
           // this is the first time the app has been installed on the device
           // so we need to set the deadLine to N number of days after the installation

           final deadLineDate = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 2)); // 2 days from the date that the app was installed;


           sharedPrefs.setString(deadLineDate.toIso8601String()); // set it so we can check on the successfull state

          return;

         }

         final deadLineDate = DateTime.parse(deadLine); // since we stored it as a string;
          /// the deadline is set and is not null

         if(DateTime.now().compareTo(deadLineDate) == 0) {
          we are successfull, N hours have passed since the intial instalation, now we can disable the button

             shouldButtonBeActive = false; // the button should be disabled
         }

       })

 }

  Widget build(context) {

      // in your UI where you use the button 

       MaterialButton(
         child: Text("Button"),
         onPressed: shouldButtonBeActive ? func() : null
       )
   }
}
```

PS: we are using the Future inside the initState, because initState dose not allow async ( api calls, storage access) in it.

Comment: What is this import?? What it does? 
It doesn't worked on my code...

Comment: its a package , you need to install it in puv.dev